# Stereo camera calibration using OpenCV results in even more distortion

Tags: camera-calibration, opencv, distortion, python

I am trying to calibrate a stereo VGA camera (640x480 greyscale) using OpenCV and a 6 x 5 chessboard pattern (0.033m square size). I took 60 pairs with the camera at a steady position, trying to vary the chessboard (see the images [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JvojT0YosZoJBW1RSpS32UO8gHnF60oh)) and started calibrating based on [this OpenCV-based tutorial](https://aliyasineser.medium.com/opencv-camera-calibration-e9a48bdd1844) and [repo](https://github.com/aliyasineser/stereoDepth). So, basically, I calibrate the two cameras first separately using the following script with width, height 5 x 4:

```
for fname in images:
    gray = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    gray = cv2.flip(gray, 0)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (width, height), None)
    if ret:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners to manually discard misalignments
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(gray, (width, height), corners2, ret)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

For the right camera, the chessboard is detected in 41/60 images. I discarded one more because of wrong alignments and recalibrated with 40 images, resulting in an RMS error of 0.11 (see calibrated files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y9eT30NH1TMDExGsHebQJ2z3a0U90gu3)). Similarly, I calibrated the left camera with 40 images which resulted in an RMS of 0.13. **I did not discard images in which the chessboard drawings were vertical instead of horizontal, could that play a role?** As for the stereo calibration, I used the following script which resulted in an RMS error of 0.23 using 36 pairs (4 were discarded because the corners were not recognized in both pictures).

```
ret_right, corners_right = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray_right, pattern_size, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)

if ret_right and os.path.isfile(right_im.replace('RIGHT', 'LEFT')):
    # Left Object Points
    left = cv2.imread(right_im.replace('RIGHT', 'LEFT'), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    gray_left = cv2.flip(left, 0)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret_left, corners_left = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray_left, pattern_size,
                                                       cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | cv2.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)

    if ret_left:
        # Object points
        objpoints.append(objp)
        # Right points
        corners2_right = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray_right, corners_right, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)

        right_imgpoints.append(corners2_right)
        # Left points
        corners2_left = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray_left, corners_left, (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)
        left_imgpoints.append(corners2_left)

ret, K1, D1, K2, D2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, left_imgpoints, right_imgpoints, K1, D1, K2, D2, image_size, None, None, cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC, criteria)
```

After calibrating I tried to undistort and rectify the images with the stereo calibrations:

```
interpolation = cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4 # also tried with cv2.INTER_LINEAR
leftMapX, leftMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(K1, D1, R1, P1, (640, 480), cv2.CV_32FC1)
left_rectified = cv2.remap(leftFrame, leftMapX, leftMapY, interpolation, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

But the resulting image was much more distorted than the original one:
[image: Original vs. ``undistorted'' image]

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: looks like calibration failed. Try to identify/filter images where the checkerboard isnt detected correctly.

Comment: @Micka Thank you for your input! As I wrote above, the chessboard got detected for 40/60 images, and I only had to discard one because the alignments were not correct. I've now added the images containing the chessboard drawings to the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GGW-gVMmFIraQwwgXWa-tA-DCaew482N) I shared above. I did not discard images in which the alignments were vertical instead of horizontal, could that play a role?

Comment: if you get "RMS error of 0.23", the calibration is probably good. that means you're using the results wrong. to say more, one would have to run your code on your data and spend time debugging this.